Identifying a 1990's English documentary on Venice
I'm looking for a particular English language documentary on Venice made in the mid 1990s that I once had a VHS recording of, but have since lost and been unable to find anywhere else. I can't be completely sure but I think I first watched this in 1996 on the Australian TV channel SBS.
It explored writers' and artists' perceptions of Venice down the ages, how these have shaped the broader perception of the city, as well as the history of the city and the actual reality of living in Venice. It features extensive quotations from famous writers who have written about Venice, such as Hemingway, Thomas Mann, Ezra Pound, Gore Vidal, Brodsky, John Ruskin, Joseph Brodsky, Ian McEwan among others, and also interviews with a number of prominent Venetian citizens, including former mayor Massimo Cacciari and aristocrat Girolamo Marcello.
The documentary was roughly an hour long, possibly up to an hour and fifteen minutes, and the narrator was English or British.
I would greatly appreciate any information that might help me to identify this documentary.

I have searched for this documentary many times on Google over the last year, but have not been able to find anything at all.

Can it be not from 90's but from 2004: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco%27s_Venice

No, it is not Francesco's Venice, which I've seen. I saw this documentary, which I've posted about, first around 1997/8 on an Australian TV channel, probably the SBS channel.

I've searched IMDB as well, without any luck.

Is it Vidal in Venice?  The hour long program aired in 1985, via National Geographic, and there is a companion book credited to Vidal but written by someone else.  

@mariusm Does this look like yours: http://www.nytimes.com/1986/06/30/arts/tv-reviews-vidal-in-venice-two-works-on-13.html

No, it is not. The narrator was English or British.
